# Sign out In ADFS2.0 with WIF application

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, wif, adfs2.0, ws-federation

i have  followed [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-federation-wif-application-step-by-step-guide(v=ws.10).aspx)  to understand WIF application with ADFS 2.0 ,
where i installed ADFS2.0 and sample application (in IIS) in same machine,now i can login to my sample application with Active Directory username and password ,but the problem is ,although i sign out from sample application it redirects me to login.aspx page but when i click back button in browser and refresh i can still be logged in ,that means my session is not expiring in my application .Do i need to clear logged in session in ADFS also ?if so how can i do that ?i have used "FederatedPassiveSignInStatus" tool that i assumed it will logout from both  application and ADFS .

[this](http://gyazo.com/b888d1148d3267497063c1fb72645bf9) is my demo in gif.

```
<wif:FederatedPassiveSignInStatus ID="FederatedPassiveSignInStatus1" 
        runat="server" OnSignedOut="OnFederatedPassiveSignInStatusSignedOut" 
        SignInButtonType="link" FederatedPassiveSignOut="true"  SignOutAction="FederatedPassiveSignOut" />

protected void OnFederatedPassiveSignInStatusSignedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

        string signoutEndpoint = "https://test-server.test.localhost/ClaimsAwareWebAppWithManagedSTS/Login1.aspx";  // This can be stored in your configuration app settings
        string signoutUrl = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(signoutEndpoint, authModule.Realm, null);

        WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(signoutUrl), new Uri("https://test-server.test.localhost/ClaimsAwareWebAppWithManagedSTS/Default.aspx"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cookie is cleared out from the browser.
However, the cookie created by the STS is not. You need to ensure that the STS is correctly receiving the signout request as this should be the case when using FederatedSignOut.

There is a good signout method from this link: [Claims Aware MVC4 App using WIF Identity and Access tool in .Net 4.5 Part II](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2013/10/09/claims-aware-mvc4-app-using-wif-identity-and-access-tool-in-net-4-5-part-ii.aspx)

```
 if (HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)

        {

            WSFederationAuthenticationModule instance = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

            instance.SignOut(false);

            SignOutRequestMessage request = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(instance.Issuer), instance.Realm);

            return new RedirectResult(request.WriteQueryString());



        }
```